# CPU Burst and I/O Burst

Tags: process, io, scheduling

If a process that currently is being executed faces an I/O Burst, will the next available process gain the CPU burst or will the processor wait until the I/O Burst of the first process finishes to continue executing the first process.

Also does this get affected by whether an algorithm is preemptive or non-preemptive?

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to try asking this on superuser.com.